# What is the Apache 2 error log timestamp format?

Tags: apache2, strftime, goaccess

I am trying to add an Apache Error Log configuration to Goaccess, and I'm stuck on the timestamp format. My current guess is `%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y`, but apparently that is incorrect, since it gives me error `Token 'Sun Sep 11 09:51:43.343399 2022' doesn't match specifier '%t'`. Can anyone tell me the default time stamp format?

**EDIT**:

I had previously changed the log format to `[%t] [%l] [pid %P] %F: %E: [client %a] %M`, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this format:

```
%a %b %d %H:%M:%S%f %Y
```

If it doesn't work try this:

```
%{%a %b %d %H:%M:%S%f %Y}t
```

Found on this [page](https://docs.vmware.com/en/vRealize-Log-Insight/8.8/com.vmware.log-insight.agent.admin.doc/GUID-1160145C-461F-48E0-BF53-03F7EBA3517C.html).